# Swinject: Using weak scope is leaking objects

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, swinject

I'm using Swinject for DI in my swift project. I think using weak object scope is leading to leaks.

I have this dummy object

```
protocol DevTestProtocol: class {}
class DevTest: DevTestProtocol {}
```

which is registered like follows (I'm using an assembly)

```
container.register(DevTestProtocol.self) { _ in
    return DevTest()
}
.inObjectScope(.weak)
```

For testing purposes I added a property in my app delegate

```
var devTest: DevTestProtocol?
```

and in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions I resolve the object then forget about it

```
self.devTest = DI.resolve(DevTestProtocol.self)!
self.devTest = nil
```

Is the DevTest instance supposed to be gone by now? 
Because it's not. It still shows in the debug memory graph as a leak.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyqxd.jpg)

I guess this isn't expected behaviour? Am I missing something?
It looks like a bug to me and it's messing up my whole setup.
What can we do about this?
[GitHub issue](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/issues/256)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no memory leak, it's just a bug in Xcode 8 memory profiling instruments. See discussing at [GitHub issues tracker](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/issues/256)

[image]

Comment: I know, the github issue was from me :)